Combine terraform output
I have defined several outputs in my terraform module and want to merge them when to have something like name + public_ip + private_ip in one line. Is this possible?
My module outputs:
output "name" {
  description = "List with names of the servers"
  value       = hcloud_server.this[*].name
}

output "public_ip" {
  description = "List with public IPv4 IPs of the instances"
  value       = hcloud_server.this[*].ipv4_address
}

output "private_ip" {
  description = "List with public IPv4 IPs of the instances"
  value       = flatten(hcloud_server.this[*].network)[*].ip
}

output "id" {
  description = "List with IDs of the servers"
  value       = hcloud_server.this[*].id
}

output "test" {
  description = "List with public IPv4 IPs of the instances"
  value       = hcloud_server.this[*]
}

I tried around with merge() but I didnt get it working
Edit:
The output of hcloud.server looks like this after applied. I need to write something becaue stackoverflow says it looks like there is too much code
Outputs:

server = [
  {
    "allow_deprecated_images" = false
    "backup_window" = ""
    "backups" = false
    "datacenter" = "nbg1-dc3"
    "delete_protection" = false
    "firewall_ids" = toset([
      1394082,
    ])
    "id" = "47294153"
    "ignore_remote_firewall_ids" = false
    "image" = "15512617"
    "ipv4_address" = "128.140.107.214"
    "ipv6_address" = ""
    "ipv6_network" = "<nil>"
    "iso" = tostring(null)
    "keep_disk" = false
    "labels" = tomap({
      "pscloud_managed-by-terraform" = "true"
    })
    "location" = "nbg1"
    "name" = "testcustomer.testproject.nbg1-dc3.dev.testserver01"
    "network" = toset([
      {
        "alias_ips" = toset([])
        "ip" = "192.168.1.1"
        "mac_address" = "86:00:00:8a:5c:a8"
        "network_id" = 4233067
      },
    ])
    "placement_group_id" = 341672
    "primary_disk_size" = 20
    "public_net" = toset([
      {
        "ipv4" = 0
        "ipv4_enabled" = true
        "ipv6" = 0
        "ipv6_enabled" = false
      },
    ])
    "rebuild_protection" = false
    "rescue" = tostring(null)
    "server_type" = "cx11"
    "shutdown_before_deletion" = false
    "ssh_keys" = tolist([
      "20782188",
    ])
    "status" = "running"
    "timeouts" = null /* object */
    "user_data" = tostring(null)
  },
]


Are all of these a single string value or a list/set? Can you add an example of what each of the three outputs look like to the question?

I've added an EDIT block to my question with what you requested

can you add an output of hcloud_server.this I'm interested in the structure

I added the whole output to my question

I created a variable hcloud_server to simulate your list ...
Below is the sample code
variable "hcloud_server" {
  type = object({
    this = list(object({
      name = string
      ipv4 = string
      network = set(object({
        ip = string
      }))
    }))
  })
  default = {
    this : [
      { name : "a", ipv4 : "10.0.0.1", network: [{ip : "10.0.1.11"}] },
      { name : "b", ipv4 : "10.0.0.2", network: [{ip : "10.0.2.22"}] },
      { name : "c", ipv4 : "10.0.0.3", network: [{ip : "10.0.3.33"}] },
    ]
  }
}

output "name" {
  description = "List with names of the servers"
  value       = var.hcloud_server.this[*].name
}

output "test" {
  value = [
    for x in var.hcloud_server.this :
    "${x.name} + ${x.ipv4} + ${tolist(x.network)[0].ip}"
  ]
}


if we run a terraform plan on that we will get:
Changes to Outputs:
  + name = [
      + "a",
      + "b",
      + "c",
    ]
  + test = [
      + "a + 10.0.0.1 + 10.0.1.11",
      + "b + 10.0.0.2 + 10.0.2.22",
      + "c + 10.0.0.3 + 10.0.3.33",
    ]


The important part here is:
for x in var.hcloud_server.this :
"${x.name} + ${x.ipv4} + ${tolist(x.network)[0].ip}"

We have a simple for loop and just a string interpolation adding what we need

Thanks for clarifying, i'm almost at the finish line, but I cant access the private_ip, cause I dont know how to access this variable in a loop. I get the following error
│ 
│   on 10-testserver.tf line 55, in output "test":
│   55:     "NAME: ${x.name}, PUBLIC_IP: ${x.ipv4_address}, PRIVATE_IP: ${x.network.ip}"
│     ├────────────────
│     │ x.network is set of object with 1 element
│ 
│ Can't access attributes on a set of objects. Did you mean to access an attribute across all elements of the set?```

@patrick_s Can you create a variable like I did reproducing the structure?

@patrick_s from the official documentation: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hetznercloud/hcloud/latest/docs/resources/server#network that network can be multiple times ... so how are you going to handle cases with more than one? Just get the first?

I dont think that there is an situation where there is more than one network block, my architecture does not provide this scenario

@patrick_s I added the code for network in my sample ... the trick is that network is a set so we just convert that to a list then we can get the first element

If you expect that there will always be exactly one network then you could write one(x.network).ip. That uses the one function to return just the single element if there is only one element in the set, or fail with an error if there is unexpectedly more than one. Since you say there will always be exactly one, the error should never occur.

(What I just proposed is an example of what's described in Using one with sets.)

Thanks @MartinAtkins that is a nice function to know
